# Mixed Delimiters in Proc Export

Tags: sas

Is there a method to make the first delimiter in an observation different to the rest? In Microsoft  SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS), there is an option to set the delimiter per column.  I wonder if there is a similar way to achieve this in SAS with an amendment to the below code, whereby the first delimiter would be tab instead and the rest pipe:

```
proc export
    dbms=csv
    data=mydata.dataset1
    outfile="E:\OutPutFile_%sysfunc(putn("&sysdate9"d,yymmdd10.)).txt"
    replace
    label;
    delimiter='|';
run;
```

For example

From:

```
var1|var2|var3|var4
```

to

```
var1     var2|var3|var4
```

...Where the large space between var1 and var2 is a tab.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide a better definition of what you want, including a worked example or two.

Comment: @Tom Added the worked example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to make a new variable that has the first two variables combined and then write that out using tab delimiter.

```
data fix ;
  length new1 $50 ;
  set have ;
  new1=catx('09'x,var1,var2);
  drop var1 var2 ;
run;
proc export data=fix ... delimiter='|' ...
```

Note that you can reference a variable in the `DLM=` option on the `FILE` statement in a data step.

```
data _null_;
  dlm='09'x ;
  file 'outfile.txt' dsd dlm=dlm ;
  set have ;
  put var1 @ ;
  dlm='|' ;
  put var2-var4 ;
run;
```

Or you could use the `catx()` trick in a `data _null` step. You also might want to use `vvalue()` function to insure formats are applied.

```
data _null_;
  length newvar $200;
  file 'outfile.txt' dsd dlm='|' ;
  set have ;
  newvar = catx('09'x,vvalue(var1),vvalue(var2));
  put newvar var3-var4 ;
run;
```

**Updated** Fixed order of delimiters to match question.

Comment: I think OP wants the opposite (tab var1-var2, then pipe var3-var20), but the answer is the same regardless of course.  Also, you'd want to just `put var1 @;` and then `put var2--var20` or whatever - it writes out the trailing delimiter before it moves on to the next bit, so the way you have it will have two tabs not one.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, I used your second code block to get the desired output.  I'll post the exact solution as a secondary answer.

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't write the "last" delimiter until it sees there are more things to write. But it must store it somewhere because it uses the value of the `DLM` that was present when the put that wrote the value before the delimiter ran and not the value that exists when the value after is put.

Answer (score 0):

Final code based on the marked answer by Tom:

```
data _null_;
  dlm='09'x ;
  file "E:\outputfile_%sysfunc(putn("&sysdate9"d,yymmdd10.)).txt" dsd dlm=dlm ;
  set work.have;
  put 
  var1  @ ;
  dlm='|';
  put   var2 var3 var4;
run;
```